# Adding data to an array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I am trying a add data to an array using a while loop but it seems to be adding the data as a string not array. Loops/arrays are something I'm still learning any help would be great.

```
$c = 0;
$numberofcustom = 5;
$defaults = array(
'title' => __('Follow Us!', 'smw'),
 'text' => ''
);
while ($c < $numberofcustom) {
    $customnumber = $c + 1;
    $defaults.=array(
        'custom' . $customnumber . 'name' => __('', 'smw'),
        'custom' . $customnumber . 'icon' => __('', 'smw'),
        'custom' . $customnumber . 'url' => __('', 'smw')
    );
    $c++;
}

print_r($defaults);
```

The problem seems to be with adding the data from the loop if I do a `print_r` just on that I just get "array" back.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I decided I don't need a multi dimensional array so I used the suggestions below and came up with

```
while( $c < $numberofcustom){
    $customnumber = $c+1;
        $defaults['custom'.$customnumber.'name'] = __('', 'smw');
        $defaults['custom'.$customnumber.'icon'] = __('', 'smw');
        $defaults['custom'.$customnumber.'url'] = __('', 'smw');
    $c++;       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
$defaults.=array(

            'custom'.$customnumber.'name' => __('', 'smw'),
            'custom'.$customnumber.'icon' => __('', 'smw'),
            'custom'.$customnumber.'url' => __('', 'smw')
             );
```

dynamic array keys are almost as bad as variables with a dynamic name. Use another array level instead:

```
$defaults[$customernumber] = array(
    'customname' => __('', 'smw'),
    'customicon' => __('', 'smw'),
    'customurl'  => __('', 'smw'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question with the solution I came up with based on your answer as I didn't need a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Eh, nothing really it just makes it harder to get the data back out (it's for a WordPress plugin)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$arrayname[] = $var`, that's the PHP syntax for appending new items. See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
$defaults[] =array(
            'custom'.$customnumber.'name' => __('', 'smw'),
            'custom'.$customnumber.'icon' => __('', 'smw'),
            'custom'.$customnumber.'url' => __('', 'smw')
             );
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work. Is there a way to add to the array without making it multi dimensional. I tried `$defaults[]= 'custom....'` and that didn't work.